# How can in write in nested cells Google Sheets / GAS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, nested

Could be a basic question. The issue is I dont know how to write a nested value from a for cycle in Google Sheets using Google Script Apps.

I tried using the code below but no results are shown neither an error or mistake. It is making me crazy. Any help how could be donde would be appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for(var j = 0; j<6;j++){
    sheet.getRange(1,j).setValue(j);
  }}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `write a nested value from a for cycle in Google Sheets using Google Script Apps`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Its about the same mechanic of print a value in a for cycle: print the first, second, third, etc value but in a cell using Google App Scripts and Google sheets; you write the code in GAS IDE and then write in Google Sheets the results

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `print the first, second, third, etc value but in a cell using Google App Scripts and Google sheets`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: `j` should start with 1 not 0

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. Could you share the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as the outcome you expect?

Comment: Also, if you're really executing the code you shared, an error should appear (both parameters you provide to `getRange` should be integers above 0, because row and column indexes start at 1).

Comment: As mentioned by @TheMaster, `sheet.getRange(r, c)` expects 1 based. So the very top left cell is `sheet.getRange(1,1)`. Your code starts with `j = 0` => `sheet.getRange(1, 0)` which is not a valid cell. As for the other issue, can you share a sample sheet?